# How to recreate a table dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating a table dynamically in a return statement from ajax. But I see only one row of the table, although debugger shows data.length as 4. How do I correct the recreating of table?

```
// using ajax return to recreate a table
// ...

if (data.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var $mytablerow = $(
            '<table>' +
                '<tbody>' +
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td id="td' + data[i].Value + '" >' +
                            data[i].Text +
                        '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                '</tbody>' +
            '</table>'
        );
    }
}

var $mylst = $("#Userslist");
$mylst.html($mytablerow);

// ....
```

Comment: you're redefining $myTableRow 4 times, as such only using the last value after the for loop.

Comment: because you are writing over the same variable `$mytablerow ` inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
using ajax return to recreate a table
...
if (data.length > 0)
{
    var $mytablerow = '<table><tbody>';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    {
        $mytablerow += $(
                  '<tr>' +
                  '<td id="td' + data[i].Value + '" >' + data[i].Text + '</td>' +
                  '</tr>');

    }
    $mytablerow += '</tbody></table>';
}

 var $mylst = $("#Userslist");
     $mylst.html($mytablerow);
....
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a variable outside the loop. For example:

```
if(data.length > 0) {
  var $myTable = '<table><tbody>';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $myTable += '<tr><td id="td' + data[i].Value + '" >' + data[i].Text + '</td></tr>';
  }
  $myTable += '</tbody></table>';
}

var $mylst = $("#Userslist");
$mylst.html($myTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have problem in your script. To fix this problem replace by this script:

```
if (data.length > 0)
{
  var $mytablerows = '<table>' + '<tbody>';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         $mytablerows += '<tr>' +
                  '<td id="td' + data[i].Value + '" >' + data[i].Text + '</td>' +
                  '</tr>';
     }
     $mytablerows += '</tbody>' + '</table>';
     var $mylst = $("#Userslist");
     $mylst.html($mytablerows);
}
```

Comment: If I change my implementation then the result $mylst = "<table><tbody>[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]</tbody></table>" , not the content of data[i].value or data[i].Text

Comment: ok I had to remove the "$mytablerow = $('tr" to "$mytablerow = 'tr", now it works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you are creating a single row table each iteration and then only adding the last table you create. You need to create the table stuff once and then iterate to create the rows.